# Angular Ngfor in json array list

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

i try capture all the content of my category[] but I want to enter the information that is inside, since sometimes you have several lists that are inside. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="category">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> category </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell  *matCellDef="let radios ">
            {{radios.categories}}  --> Get all categorie but not the content inside
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

**Component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
this.componentService.getNewlist()
.then(result => {
    if(!result){
      return;
    }
    this.getresult = result;
    let promises: any[];
    this.getresult.forEach(item=>{
        this.radiosService.getCategid(item.id).then(categories=>{
          promises = categories;
          item['categories']  = promises;
          console.log(promises); <--- GET ALL CONTENT OF MY I get all the information of my category depending on my id
        })

      });
  }) 
    .catch(reason => {
    console.log(reason);
});
```

}

**TABLE**

in my table shows me:

[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]

I want to access the information that is inside with an ngfor or [ngForOf]

I want to do everything with one to review my categories to get the data that is inside, 
try with *ngFor = "let item of categories;" // {{radios.categories.item.description}} but it did not work, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? It would be a lot easier to help you if you created a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
<mat-cell  *matCellDef="let radios ">
    <span *ngFor="let category of radios.categories">{{category.description}}</span>
</mat-cell>
```